# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findSongBySize'

Tags: python, attributes

I'm new to Ubuntu (and the Python scripts that go with it) and I've been hitting this error with the iTunesToRhythm script.

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amylee/iTunesToRhythm.py", line 220, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/home/amylee/iTunesToRhythm.py", line 48, in main
    match = correlator.correlateSong( song, options.confirm, options.fastAndLoose,  options.promptForDisambiguate )
  File "/home/amylee/iTunesToRhythm.py", line 133, in correlateSong
    matches = self.parser.findSongBySize( song.size );
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findSongBySize'**
```

I understand the concept behind fixing the issue but have no idea how to go about it.  I've looked at answers to similar problems but none really help me, especially since I have no clue as to what I am doing.  I've included the full script below.  Thanks in advance, dudes who know way more about this stuff than I do.

----iTunesToRhythm.py----

```
import sys
import platform

if platform.system() == "Darwin":
    sys.path.append('/sw/lib/python2.5/site-packages/')
    from dumpitunesmac import iTunesMacParser, iTunesMacSong

import libxml2
import linecache
from optparse import OptionParser,  OptionGroup
from dumprhythm import RhythmLibraryParser, RhythmSong
from dumpitunes import iTunesLibraryParser, iTunesSong

def main(argv):
    # process command line
    options, args = processCommandLine(argv)
    print "Reading input from " + args[0]
    inputParser = getParser(args[0], options  )
    print "Writing to output " + args[1]
    destinationParser = getParser(args[1], options  )

    #retrieve destination songs
    allDestinationSongs = destinationParser.getSongs()

    # go through each song in destination library
    correlator = SongCorrelator(inputParser)
    for song in allDestinationSongs:
        print song.artist + " - " + song.album + " - " + song.title + " - " + str(song.size)
        if song.size != None and song.size != "Unknown":
            # find equivalent itunes song
            match = correlator.correlateSong( song, options.confirm, options.fastAndLoose,  options.promptForDisambiguate )
            # update database, if match
            if match != None and options.writeChanges == True:
                if options.noratings == False:
                    song.setRating( match.rating  )
                    print "\t\t\tRating changed to " + str( match.rating )
                if options.noplaycounts == False:
                    song.setPlaycount( match.playcount )
                    print "\t\t\tPlay count changed to " + str( match.playcount )

    # dump summary results
    print "\nSummary\n------------------------------------"
    print "manually resolved matches = " + str( correlator.manuallyResolvedMatches)
    print "full matches = " + str( correlator.fullMatches )
    print "partial matches = " + str( correlator.partialMatches)
    print "no matches = " + str( correlator.zeroMatches )
    print "unresolved ambiguous matches = " + str( correlator.ambiguousMatches )

    # save
    if options.writeChanges == True:
        destinationParser.save()
        print "Changes were written to destination"
    else:
        print "Changes were not written to destination \n\tuse -w to actually write changes to disk" 

def getParser(  file,  options ):
    if file == "mysql":
        print "\tassuming amarok database"
        return AmarokLibraryParser(options.servername, options.database, options.username,  options.password   )
    if file == "itunes":
        print "\tassuming itunes on the mac"
        return iTunesMacParser()

    desc = linecache.getline( file,  2)
    if desc.find("Apple Computer") != -1:
        #open itunes linbrary
        print "\tdetected Itunes library"
        return iTunesLibraryParser(file);
    if desc.find("rhythmdb") != -1:
        print "\tdetected Rhythm box library"
        return RhythmLibraryParser(file)

def processCommandLine( argv ):
    parser = OptionParser("iTunesToRhythm [options] <inputfile>|itunes|mysql <outputfile>|mysql|itunes")
    parser.add_option("-c", "--confirm", action="store_true", dest="confirm", default = False, help="confirm every match" )
    parser.add_option("-w", "--writechanges", action="store_true", dest="writeChanges", default = False, help="write changes to destination file" )
    parser.add_option("-a", "--disambiguate", action="store_true", dest="promptForDisambiguate", default = False, help="prompt user to resolve ambiguities" )
    parser.add_option("-l",  "--fastandloose", action="store_true", dest= "fastAndLoose",  default = False,  help = "ignore differences in files name when a file size match is made against  a single song.   Will not resolve multiple matches" )
    parser.add_option("--noplaycounts", action="store_true", dest= "noplaycounts",  default = False,  help = "do not update play counts" )
    parser.add_option("--noratings", action="store_true", dest= "noratings",  default = False,  help = "do not update ratings" )

    amarokGroup = OptionGroup(parser,  "Amarok options",  "Options for connecting to an Amarok MySQL remote database")
    amarokGroup.add_option("-s",  "--server",  dest="servername",  help = "host name of the MySQL database server")
    amarokGroup.add_option("-d",  "--database",  dest="database",  help = "database name of the amarok database")
    amarokGroup.add_option("-u",  "--username",  dest="username",  help = "login name of the amarok database")
    amarokGroup.add_option("-p",  "--password",  dest="password",  help = "password of the user")

    parser.add_option_group(amarokGroup)
    # parse options
    options, args = parser.parse_args()

    # check that files are specified
    if len(args) != 2:
            parser.print_help()
            parser.error( "you must supply 2 file names or 1 file name and the word mysql followed by database information.  Specyfing itunes will use a running instance of iTunes on the Mac" )

    # make surce source & destination are not the same
    if args[0] == args[1]:
        parser.error("source and destination cannot be the same")

    # we're ok
    return options, args

class SongCorrelator:
    def __init__(self, parser ):
        self.parser = parser
        self.zeroMatches = 0
        self.fullMatches = 0
        self.ambiguousMatches = 0;
        self.partialMatches = 0;
        self.manuallyResolvedMatches = 0;

    # attempt to find matching song in database
    def correlateSong( self, song, confirm, fastAndLoose,  promptForDisambiguate ):
        match = None
        matches = self.parser.findSongBySize( song.size );
        matchcount = len(matches)

        # no results
        if matchcount == 0:
            print "\t no matches found"
            self.zeroMatches = self.zeroMatches + 1
        # full match
        elif matchcount == 1:
            match = matches[0]
            if match.title == song.title:
                print "\t 100% match on " + self.dumpMatch( match )
                self.fullMatches = self.fullMatches + 1
            else:
                if fastAndLoose == False:
                    match = self.disambiguate( song, matches, promptForDisambiguate )
                else:
                    print "\t 50% match on " + self.dumpMatch( match )
                    self.partialMatches = self.partialMatches + 1
        # multiple matches
        else:
            print "\t multiple matches"
            for match in matches:
                print "\t\t " + self.dumpMatch( match )
            # attempt a resolution
            match = self.disambiguate( song, matches, promptForDisambiguate )

        #review
        if confirm == True:
            foo = raw_input( 'press <enter> to continue, Ctrl-C to cancel')

        #done
        return match

    def dumpMatch(  self, match ):
        return match.title + ", playcount = " + str(match.playcount) + ", rating = " + str(match.rating)

    def disambiguate(self,song,matches,prompt):
        # attempt to disambiguate by title
        print "\t looking for secondary match on title"
        titlematchcount = 0
        for match in matches:
            if match.title == song.title:
                titlematchcount = titlematchcount + 1
                latstitlematch = match

        if titlematchcount == 1:
            # we successfully disambiguated using the title
            print "\t\t disambiguated using title"
            self.fullMatches = self.fullMatches + 1
            return latstitlematch

        if prompt == True:
            print "\t\t cannot disambiguate.  Trying to match " + song.filePath
            print "Please select file or press <Enter> for no match:"
            numMatch = 0
            for match in matches:
                numMatch = numMatch + 1
                print "\t\t\t\t[" + str(numMatch) + "] " + self.dumpMatch(match) + ", " + match.filePath

            selection = self.inputNumber("\t\t\t\t? ", 1, len(matches) )
            if selection > 0:
                self.manuallyResolvedMatches = self.manuallyResolvedMatches + 1
                return matches[selection - 1]

        # user did not select, record ambiguity
        self.ambiguousMatches = self.ambiguousMatches + 1
        return None

    def inputNumber(self, msg, min, max):
        result = raw_input(msg)
        if len(result) == 0:
            return 0
        try:
            resultNum = int(result)

            if resultNum < min or resultNum > max:
                print "out of range"
                return self.inputNumber( msg, min, max )

            return resultNum
        except:
            print "invalid input"
            return self.inputNumber(msg, min, max)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Are you a programmer or a user of this script? This site is for programming questions, not "How do I use application X?". For that try superuser.com for example.

Comment: `if match != None` is bad. You should use `if match is not None` instead. Always use `is` (identity comparison) for None. Comparing a bool to True is also needless, just do `... and options.writeChanges`, `if not options.noratings`, etc.

Comment: Just a user for now but I figured I should learn how to fix these mistakes and after looking around it seemed like the best place to get my question answered.  I'll definitely try out superuser.com in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: @Amy: This code is pretty terrible. Where did you get it? I have an urge to de-crap it now...

Comment: http://www.esanbock.com/iTunesToRhythm/iTunesToRhythm.html

Comment: Oh boy, what a chore this will be... pylint: `Your code has been rated at -4.73/10`

Answer (score 7):

I'm the original developer.  I updated the script to throw an exception if the file format is not recognized (I think this is what you are running into).  I also incorporated some useful patches from another user.

Please download the files again and e-mail me if you still have trouble.

Comment: Thanks for updating so quickly :)

Comment: Rockin, thanks Doug!  And thank you for writing this script!!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be that `getParser` is returning `None`, presumably because all the if conditions have failed.

Check that `args[0]` and `options` are the values that you expect them to be.

I'd suggest raising an exception at the end of the `getParser` method if the arguments are not valid so that the error is raised close to the cause of the problem rather in some unrelated code much later.